# google script for value in data does not work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tested my javascript code offline, it is working fine. However, when I try the same code in google script, it does not work same way as offline. Code is like this:

```
   function myfunction(){
    Data = [
{
    "prefix": [
        {
            "prefix": "rr",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "rdf",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "xsd",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "rdfs",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "domain",
            "uri": "http://example.com/"
        }
    ],
    "rr:subjectMap": [
        {
            "rr:class": "Person"
        },
        {
            "rr:template": "notemplate"
        }
    ],
    "predicatesObjectMapsArray": [
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "firstName"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "lastName"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "id"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "department"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "phoneNumber"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 5
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rr:logicalTable": [
        {
            "rr:logicalTable": "Person"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "prefix": [
        {
            "prefix": "rr",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "rdf",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "xsd",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "rdfs",
            "uri": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
        },
        {
            "prefix": "domain",
            "uri": "http://example.com/"
        }
    ],
    "rr:subjectMap": [
        {
            "rr:class": "Company"
        },
        {
            "rr:template": "notemplate"
        }
    ],
    "predicatesObjectMapsArray": [
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "id"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "employer"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rr:predicateObjectMap": [
                {
                    "rr:predicate": "employerid"
                },
                {
                    "rr:objectMap": [
                        {
                            "rr:datatype": "xsd:string",
                            "rr:template": "none",
                            "rr:column": 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rr:logicalTable": [
        {
            "rr:logicalTable": "Company"
        }
    ]
}]
for (var i=0; i<Data.length; i++) {
           for (var triple in Data[i]) { 
              Logger.log(triple); 
            }
 }
```

Logger.log result is 000000000...

I suspect that, may be (for value in Data) working differently in google script. Or does it work normal in general? Should I look for error in different place, than for?

Answer (score 0):

The following example works as expected in GAS:

```js
function myfunction(Data) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var value in Data) {
    sum += Data[value];
  }
  return sum;
}

function test_myfunction() {
  var Data = [1, 2, 3];
  var result = myfunction(Data);
  Logger.log(6 === result); // True
}
```

Can you post an example with details of your particular case? That will help us help you.

**UPDATE**

I can not reproduce the problem. The following is what I get as output using your code:

[image]

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, testing your code local or in appsscript return the same result as wchiquito post. what do you use "Data" for an argument that you pass to html service or something like that?